# Need help in storing in the array struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I m a beginner in programming and right now I'm learning go lang and this question might be simple. I have a declaration as follows:

```
var list []struct {
    Name    string
    Value string
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to initialize a variable inside this. Appreciate any help.

I have tried

```
    list[0].Name="12"
    list[0].Value="123"
    // this throws an index out of range exception..
```

Comment: Don't you need to first **allocate** an entry for index 0 (and, of course, any additional entry)?

Comment: As i have learned, we need to use make keyword for the allocation.But for this i dont know how to allocate or am i wrong???.Please help me .Thanks

Comment: I don't know the language you are using, but you may try looking for the command `new`, which in many languages means _allocate space for a new object (in your case) into an array_.

Comment: Whats your goal? Define a struct and initiate values?

Comment: If you are new to Go: Take the Tour of Go. You will learn much more and faster than asking here. Your problem is covered in https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6 and the following handful of pges.

Comment: Thanks Volker. I  learned how to do this from your link..I will learn from tour of go lang first  .It seems a good documentation....

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you have to declare a type of struct outside of the main scope :

```
type myStruct struct {
   Name  string
   Value string
}
```

Then you say to go, "i want an slice of x of this struct" :

```
list := make([]myStruct, 5)
```

Then you just fill your struct with the right index :

```
list[0].Name = "12"
list[0].Value = "123"
```

Comment: Thats technically a slice, not an array.

Comment: Yep that's true, my bad. I'm mixing between C and Go.

Answer (score 0):

Following approach might be the one you are looking.

```
package main
import ("fmt")
type YourType struct {
    Name, Value string
}
var ListOfTypes=[]YourType{
    {Name:"NameOne",Value:"ValueOne"},
    {Name:"NameTwo",Value:"ValueTwo"},
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(ListOfTypes[0]) // This will print {NameOne ValueOne}
    ListOfTypes[0].Name="NewValue"
    fmt.Println(ListOfTypes[0]) //{NewValue ValueOne}
}
```